# YAML store expression language

Tags: spring-boot, yaml

I am trying to store an expression language in `YAML` file

```
"name": "${foo.data:toLower().equals('hello')}"
```

I tried putting `'\'` in front of `'$'` and `{}`, but it doesn't work.
I just want to set the `"name"` key to the expression language above.

Failed attempts results `name` key to get a property with `"toLower().equals('hello')"`

Comment: I've found that just escaping the open brace seems to prevent the expression from being resolved, i.e.: `name: $\{test:foo}` (without the double-quotes that you've used) resolves to the literal String "$\{test:foo}". But the backslash remains, so you'd have to remove that from your String when its used later, which I guess doesn't really help? If you know that your `name` property is going to contain SpEL, could you make it: `name: foo.data:toLower().equals('hello')`, and just wrap it in the `${...}` in code?

Comment: @DaveyDaveDave thanks for your help. i just put ${...} later in code.

Answer (score 0):

If you put a backslash (`\`) in front of the `$` within the double quoted string, you should get an error because `\$` is an unknown escape sequence in YAML.

If you don't get that error, your parser is broken, but you might be able to get around that by using double backslashes:

```
"name": "\\${foo.data:toLower().equals('hello')}"
```

(you may also need them for the `{` and `}`)